# Importing Python3 flask gives werkzeug.test not found in yocto distribution?

Tags: flask, pip, yocto, pypi, bitbake

I have installed the flask using meta-python layer in my yocto OS. But when i try to import the flask it gives the error of werkzeug.test.

```
>>> import flask
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
from . import json
File "/user/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
from werkzeug.http import http_date
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
from . test import Client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug.test'
```

how can i fix it? is there something related to version issue?

Comment: Check that you have `/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py`. If not — reinstall `werkzeug`.

Comment: its not there, i have added the werkzeug through a recipe but it doesnt contain test.py somehow. do you know if it is with the new version that way?

Comment: It's in 1.0.1: https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/1dde4b1790f9c46b7122bb8225e6b48a5b22a615/src/werkzeug/test.py. Try to reinstall `werkzeug`.

Comment: yeah you are right, its there. but , i reinstalled it still werkzeug.test is not there..

Comment: it worked, something was happening with version number. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @phd. I figured out that recipe of werkzeug version 1.0.1 was not included in the meta-python layer. Copying the recipe 1.0.1 from the repo and bitbake the recipe again solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

The python3-werkzeug recipe create a tests package, to solve simply install it in your image.

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "python3-werkzeug-tests"
```